# What will the output of this script be?

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
q=3
while q = 3
 do
  echo blah
  q=‘expr $q + 1‘
 done
```

I am getting ready for an exam and have come across this question. I am confused on what the output will be.

I think the output will be an error. The reason being that  "while q = 3" should be "while q -eq 3" instead.

If someone can give me a good explain of this piece of code that would be really nice and helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes, but the only thing I get back is s: line 2: q: command not found

Comment: Well, that's the output of the script, then, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
while q = 3
```

doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you intention was to check if q is 3.
Then you should have done

```
while [ "$q" -eq 3 ] # or better while (( q == 3 )). See [1]
```

Also note that

```
 while q=3 #No spaces around = during assignment.
 do
 #stuff
 done
```

would also have been syntactically correct but logically wrong.

Also note that,

```
 q=‘expr $q + 1‘ # that should have been backticks ` instead of single quote '
```

ie

```
q=`expr $q + 1`
```

is the correct usage

Perhaps, many shells now a days support a construct like

```
(( q++ )) # same effect as  q=`expr $q + 1`
```

---

<sup>**[ 1 ]** The `(( ))` will take care of unset `q` by replacing it with zero</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking. So it would be an error as the output.